# When I use the protege to perform SWRL reasoning, I am reminded that prefix name not registered

Tags: ontology

I am using protege to build an ontology and use the SWRL rules provided with the software for reasoning. When creating a new SWRL rule, I was reminded "protege prefix not registered for prefix name". Many thanks here, can someone tell me how to register the prefix name?

Comment: I've solved it，when modify the Ontology IRI, the Ontology Prefixes need modify same time, and the name cannot contain '_'

Comment: Please add your comment as a answer to help other ones with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too when I used the SWRLTab and the SQWRLTab.
I like to edit my turtle files with an IDE instead of using protege. I prefer this as I end up with a much cleaner and shorter file.
I still use Protege for a better visualization of my Ontology, to use reasoners, etc.

I personally use the Turtle format but this solution should work with all the other formats too,  just make sure to adapt it to yours in the right way.

The problem for me was that I stored the Ontology IRI using only the `@base` declaration.

```
@base <MY_ONTOLOGY_IRI> .
```

I did some exploration and find out that Protege also saves a prefix as follow:

```
@prefix _: <MY_ONTOLOGY_IRI> .
```

This causes the SWRLTab and the SQWRLTab to expect to find  the `_:` prefix. I think this can happen only if the Ontology is written by hand like in my case. Doesn't matter your situation, just make sure that the `@prefix _:` and the `@base` declaration have the same value and You should be fine.

⚠️ **An additional note:**
After adding the `@prefix` from my IDE, Protege asked to reload the Ontology with a pop-up. Reloading it was not enough for me. I had to restart Protege completely to make it work.